# вопрос по $(this)

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добрый день

```
        $('.menu li').hover(
            function() {
                $(this).animate({'marginLeft':'5'}, 100);
                // тут хочу получить   $(this)(a) т.е. $('.menu li a')
            },
            function() {
                $(this).animate({'marginLeft':'0'}, 100);
            }
        );
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(this).find('a')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.menu li').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find('a').animate({'marginLeft':'5'}, 100);
            // тут хочу получить   $(this)(a) т.е. $('.menu li a')
    },
    /* ... */
);
```